# MySql increment or not based on a previous value

Tags: mysql, sql

In the below sql, I'm trying to increment the rank, based on the perCent column. The thing here is, that the rank should remain the same when a similar score is found.

```
select id, perCent, 
       @curRank := if( parent = @prevParent and perCent != @prevPerCent , @curRank + 1, 1) AS rank,

       @prevParent := parent, @prevPerCent := perCent
from (
    select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
    from likesd parent
    join likesd child
       on parent.id = child.parent
    where parent.type = 3
    order by parent.id, child.perCent desc) x
cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevPerCent := null) r
```

Eg: 50 is rank 1, 30 is rank 2, 30 is again rank 2, 20 is rank 3. The idea is to not increment when a similar rank is found.

How do I do that? How can I tell MySql in the `if` statement not to incremwnt it?

The basic logic is

```
if parent = @prevParent, if perCent = @prevPerCent
// Dont increment
else
increment
```

I'm stuck with this part in MySql. Can you help?

**Main Table**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "35"    "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "35"    "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"

"29"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "50"    "0"
"30"    "3"     "29"        "US"        "50"    "0"
"31"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "20"    "40.00"
"32"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "25.00"
"33"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "35.00"
```

**Expected results:**

```
"id"    "perCent" "rank"
"26"    "50.00"   "1"
"27"    "33.33"   "2" 
"28"    "33.33"   "2" // No increment in rank if the perCent is same as above

"31"    "40.00"    "1" // Continious incrementing here. PerCents differ.
"33"    "35.00"    "2"
"32"    "25.00"    "3"
```

**Some more effort that dont work (Ugh! I give up)**

```
select id, perCent, 
      @curRank := if(parent = @prevParent, TRUE, FALSE) AS rank,

      @curCent := if(perCent = @prevCent, FALSE, TRUE) AS cent,

      @curRank := if(@curRank and @curCent, @curRank + 1,'No Inc') AS k,

       @prevParent := parent, @prevCent := perCent
from (
    select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
    from likesd parent
    join likesd child
       on parent.id = child.parent
    where parent.type = 3
    order by parent.id, child.perCent desc) x
cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevCent := null) r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac996/7

```
select id, perCent, rank
from
(
    select id, perCent 
    , @curRank :=   
        case 
           when @prevParent = parent then
               case
                   --if parents are the same and values are the same, rank is the same
                   when @prevCent = perCent then @curRank 
                   --if same parents but different values, increment the rank
                   else @curRank + 1
               end
           --if parents are different, reset the rank
           else 1
        end rank
    , @prevParent := parent
    , @prevCent := perCent
    from 
    (
        select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
        from likesd parent
        inner join likesd child
           on child.parent = parent.id
        where parent.type = 3
        order by parent.id
        , child.perCent desc
    ) x
    cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevCent := null) r
) y
```

Comment: The fiddle works well, but do you know why I get `/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'rank' in 'field list' */` when I test on my local machine? There's no col in the fiddle either, but that works well there.

Comment: Ok. Everything works beautifully. I copied the code from the fiddle. That one works perfect. Thanks for helping with this. I wish I could code like you. When I figure out how to, I will award a bounty for this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd wrapped the inner SQL in an outer SQL and forgot to add the column name to the inner SQL on the above version - now added.  To be honest, you did all the clever stuff above - I just made a little tweak / swapped the `if`s for `case` statements.  Good luck with it going forwards.